# ASP.NET Core get Resource string from explicit culture

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

On my ASP.NET Core 3.1 website I'm trying to generate alternate links for different supported languages. These links are stored in resources. I'm using IStringLocalizer<> as a dependency in my class to get the translations. There used to be an extension method .WithCulture() that allowed string localizer to lookup in different culture. However this is marked obsolete (and removed in .NET 5).

What is the best approach to load single key from multiple available cultures?
I'm currently "hacking" it using this approach

```cs
var originalCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(cultureCode);
var localized = localizer[myKey];
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = originalCulture;
```

for each supported language.
However this simply doesn't seem right to me.

Is there a better approach?

Also I think there is some kind of race condition as I encountered some texts being randomly rendered in incorrect culture - because I¨M changing some global state..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store it in appSettings.json or other json file?

Comment: Because I don't want to build the mechanism around to pick to correct one based on language when using it all around the app